# $n$th root of $x$ - technical term for $n$?

Tags: terminology, radicals

As you can see in the title, I want to know how the number before a root is called.

For example, if you have the cubic root of 8, I want to know how the 3 before the roof is called.

Actually, I already know it - but in German... In German, it's called "Wurzelexponent".

If I translate that german eord into English, it is "root exponent".
Is that correct?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it has an official name.  "root power" or "root to the n-th power" the "inverse power" or "exponential root" "root exponent" "inverse exponent" would all be understood in context.

Answer (score 1):

The most common term I've seen for $n$ in the expression $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is the *index*, or *root index*.

Wikipedia's article on [$n$th roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) mentions this, but only twice (for the first time in the third paragraph of the page).

Comment: Earlier in that same Wikipedia page the term "degree" is used (which I find more natural).

Comment: @RobArthan *Degree* is new to me, and it does seem pretty fitting. For whatever reason, at least in lower level classes, "index" is all I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

*n* is called the **order** of the root, since the expression is “the root of **order** *n*”.